# Eigenstates of total spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, linear-algebra, quantum-states

Is it possible for a single electron to fail to be in an eigenstate of the total spin operator?

Are there any examples where they are not in an eigenstate of total spin?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for a single electron to fail to be in an eigenstate of the total spin operator?

No. The *spin* of a single electron is always 1/2.

So the eigenvalue of total spin is always $\sqrt{3}/2$.

Answer (score 0):

A state written in the $jj$ coupling scheme will not necessarily have good total spin.  On the other hand states in the $LS$ coupling scheme *will* by construction have good $S$.

Comment: OP seems to be asking about a *single* electron and the total *spin* operator, not total angular momentum. In this case it seems like the answer is trivially just "no."

Comment: @hft “…examples where *they are* not…” does not sound like a one-electron question…

Comment: Look at the updated question. It now reads "a single electron."

Comment: @hft yeah but still plural.  I do not like it when OP edits a question so as to totally change its meaning *after* answers have been posted.

Comment: I guess it is up to OP to clarify